# gnuplot timestamp format from double number (13dig. epoch)

Tags: gnuplot, javaplot

I have a file with strings

```
1.429520882432E12 3432.0 
1.429520882914E12 1573.0
...
```

first col is epoch timestamp(13 digit), how could I get time from it? I couldnt find format for 'double' digits

I export it from javaplot program and `plot 'file' using ($1*1000000000000):2` doesn't fit, but if I can do it with javaplot, it's great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you multiplicate the values by 100000000... ? The values are already given as floating point number in milliseconds. You have to divide them by 1000. Doing this, I get this output, which perfectly fits your 432 and 914 milliseconds:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"                   # Format in file
set format x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.3S" # Format of axis labels
set xtics 0.05                     # One label every 50ms
set xtics rotate by 30 right       # Labels are looong...
set grid

plot "timedData.csv" u (($1/1000)):2 with linespoints
```